# make_blobs without Sklearn

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I would like to write exactly this code but without the Sklearn importation :

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
X_Train, Y_Train = make_blobs(n_samples=100, n_features=2, centers=2, random_state=0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually check the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0d378913b/sklearn/datasets/_samples_generator.py#L792) for generating the blobs. In it you can find the parts for making the matrix.

In theory, one way is to generate a [multivariate normal distribution](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.multivariate_normal.html) with 2 different means and similar standard deviation, for example if there's only 2 relevant features, you can set the means

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

means = [[1,1],[3,3]]
covs = [[0.5,0],[0,0.5]]
n = 100
np.random.seed(1223)

X = np.vstack([np.random.multivariate_normal(i, covs, n) for i in means])
y = np.repeat([0,1],n)
plt.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1],c = y)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image]